# how to sync database with a github and psql database using rails

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, github

This might sound as a noob question but I have a project that is using PSQL and Rails.
It is hosted on heroku.

My friend would like to help me with the development of this project.
Let's say he clones my heroku project and sets up his own database locally, makes changes to its schema and etc and pushes it.

Meanwhile I am also making changes to my local database, maybe working on another table, updating fields etc and push my code.

How can we have the database in sync? How can we each get the most recent version of the database with its most recent data?

Do we have to import/export the database schema all the time? Wouldn't this override our changes and data?

Any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you never push your local database to Heroku, instead write migrations and run them against your remote database `heroku run rake db:migrate` and rake tasks that make any changes to the data you need.

To retrieve your database you can use `heroku db:pull` although I would be more inclined to use the pg:transfer plugin (https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-pg-transfer) which does a PSQL backup on Heroku and then restores it locally.

You'll need to get into a good habit of pushing your changes to github and then frequently pulling to minimise the risk but git does a pretty good job of merging changes. Also, consider implementing some kind of CI server and have a chat channel (hipchat, campfire etc) which shares the commit messages between yourselves so you know what the other has been up to.

Comment: This is amazing, I wasn't aware of the plugin. 
Thank you!